# building the thread pool in spark streaming program

Tags: apache-spark, streaming

To avoid delaying and to speed up the process,i build the thread pool in the spark streaming. The main program is listed as follows:

```
stream.foreachRDD(rdd=> {
  rdd.foreachPartition { rddPartition => {
    val client: Client = ESClient.getInstance.getClient
    var num = Random.nextInt()
    val threadPool: ExecutorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5)
    val confs = new Configuration()
    rddPartition.foreach(x => {
      threadPool.execute(new esThread(x._2, num, client, confs))
    }        )      }     }    }    )
```

The function of the esThread is that firstly,we inquire the elasticsearch,then we get the query result of ES,finally we write the result to HDFS. But we find data of the result file in HDFS lack a lot,which is a little left. I wonder that we can build the thread pool in the spark streaming. Does the thread pool in spark streaming make some data missing?

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Partitions are processed by separate threads already, and stream won't proceed to the next batch until the previous one has finished. So it is not likely to buy you anything and makes resource usage tracking less transparent.

At the same time, as your code is implemented at this moment, you're likely to loose data. Since `threadPool` doesn't `awaitTermination`, parent thread might exit before all data has been processed.

Overall it is not useful approach. If you want to increase throughput you should tune number of partitions and amount of computing resources.

Comment: thanks for your answer, there are also some question.1.dose 'the parent thread' refer to the partition thread?2.what do you mean that threadPool doesn't awaitTermination?Does the approach work if I make threadPool awaitTermination?Owing to the limit of the computing resources i can get, I want to make more threads to increase the throughput.